# Navigating to main view of Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a list of views that are in a navigation controller. I have my main page, with my start button, and other button. Upon clicking the start button, my app loads the second page with more buttons, upon selecting those buttons, i load a 3rd view. I cannot figure out how to go from the 3rd view in my stack, all the way back to my main view without having to take the time to navigate through each view using the back button; all thanks and appreciation in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried that earlier, but I didn't have the Animated on the end, so yea. Anyways, thanks for the help. God Bless You! John 3:16